# Getting SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, ssl, jsse, sni

I am referring to this [`JSSE Reference Guide`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#ex2) and doing `handshake` with my Webserver with an `SNI` Hostname and getting the public certificate.

Only for a particular SNI Domain, when I try to get the Pub-Cert with `ssl-handshake` I am getting the below exception

> Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

It comes exactly when i `wrap` the data using `sslEngine.wrap(myAppData, myNetData);`

Am not sure how to tackle it ..

But when i try to do the handshake from my `linux-terminal` with the below command, it works perfectly fine ..

```sh
/usr/bin/openssl s_client -connect api.sys.mm.d1.cf.company.com:443 -servername www.myapp.company.com 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: These exceptions usually come up when the root certificate is not trusted. You may need to add the root certificate (the top most certificate in your certificate chain) to the trust store. Other possibility, is that your server does not return the whole certificate chain (excluding the root certificate) when requested.

Comment: you can also try to update your JDK

Comment: the same `JDK` ran my code well 1 month back. Now am running in to the issue... Would that be a good option to use libraries such as `bouncy-castle` to make `SSL` calls and read the ceritificate, as opposed to using `java-NIO` apis ?